# Please help me set up a Context Menu in an AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've been working at this all day, and I'm really close but just can't get this to work. I have a button that pulls up an AlertDialog populated with saved entries that include Name and Price. Right now, I can click an item in the Dialog and have it automatically fill in the Name and Price fields in my activity. I want to also be able to long press an item and receive an option to delete it. This is my first try at an Android app, and a lot of this is repurposed from the Notepad Tutorial. Two things I can't figure out:

1) Is my registerForContextMenu sufficient/correct?

2) What am I doing wrong with my onCreateContextMenu?

Thanks.

```
savedItems.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {

      cDbHelper.open();
      mNotesCursor = cDbHelper.fetchAllSaved();
            startManagingCursor(mNotesCursor);

            // Create an array of names and corresponding prices from db
            String[] from = new String[]{SavedItemsDbAdapter.KEY_NAME, SavedItemsDbAdapter.KEY_PRICE};

            // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to
            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2};

            // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
            SimpleCursorAdapter saved = 
                 new SimpleCursorAdapter(NewEntry.this, R.layout.saved_row, mNotesCursor, from, to);

      // Build an AlertDialog to hold this list
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewEntry.this);
      builder.setTitle("Choose from list");
      // IS THIS SUFFICIENT TO REGISTER FOR CONTEXT MENU?
      registerForContextMenu(v);
      builder.setAdapter(saved, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

       // When an item from the list is clicked, it automatically populates the name and price fields in activity
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
 Cursor c = mNotesCursor;
       c.moveToPosition(item);
 Intent i = new Intent(NewEntry.this, NewEntry.class);
       i.putExtra("name", c.getString( 
         c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SavedItemsDbAdapter.KEY_NAME)));
       i.putExtra("price", c.getString(
         c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SavedItemsDbAdapter.KEY_PRICE)));
       startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_AUTO);
       finish();
}

      // TRYING AND FAILING TO SET UP A CONTEXT MENU - the goal is to be able to long press, 
      // have a "Delete?" option pop up, which will delete the entry when clicked 
      @Override
      public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
   }

   public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
       case DELETE_ID:
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        mDbHelper.deleteItem(info.id);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
   }
      });

      AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

         alert.show();

        }

     });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is my registerForContextMenu sufficient/correct?

You are registering a context menu for whatever `savedItems` is. If that is what you want the context menu on, then you are OK.

If your goal is to have a context menu on the items in the list in the dialog, your approach is wrong. You will not be able to use `AlertDialog.Builder`. You will need to create a custom subclass of `AlertDialog`, so you can override `onCreateContextMenu()` there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any possibility you could point me in the right direction for creating a custom subclass of AlertDialog? Thanks.

Comment: I am going to spend the night with this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: @evanl81: No, that sample is not quite right for your needs, either. You need to create a *custom subclass* of `AlertDialog` (or `Dialog`, whichever), such as http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-ui-colored-dialogs.html  You may find it simpler to use a dialog-themed `Activity` (`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` in your manifest entry for the `Activity`).

Comment: I originally did use Theme.Dialog, but I thought it looked sort of ugly. I will take a look through your link, thanks.

Comment: @evanl81: " but when I try to run the application I get a message that it has errors (which it doesn't)" -- I am assuming you are using Eclipse. Check your console log. Consider using Project > Clean to see if that helps. "Do I need to declare the dialog somewhere" -- no.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, I quickly deleted that as I learned it was an issue with a non-existent image...

Answer (score 1):

I just found

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
```

to be called, but not

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
```

in my subclassed AlertDialog:

```
public class MyAlertDialog extends AlertDialog implements
OnCreateContextMenuListener {
```

Perhaps this is useful to someone else as I'm pretty sure you have meanwhile solved your problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You only need implement the following function. It will work.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{
    Log.e(LOGTAG, "Tao menu");
    if(v == expList)
    {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        //AdapterContextMenuInfo aInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

        // We know that each row in the adapter is a Map
        //HashMap map =  (HashMap) simpleAdpt.getItem(aInfo.position);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
        menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Reprint");
        menu.add(1, 2, 1, "Void");

        menu.getItem(0).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener()
        {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem clickedItem)
            {
                return true;
            }
        });

        menu.getItem(1).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener()
        {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem clickedItem)
            {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```